# Storyboard - setting delegates

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, delegates, uistoryboard

Before storyboards I was able to set delegates and datasources just by dragging an outlet to a class. With storyboards, I cannot drag the outlet to another view controller; there is no destination that will respond to it.

If I click on a view controller object, I am able to see the class owner at the bottom, but as soon as I select the other view controller containing the outlet, the old selection is gone, so I cannot connect the two.

Is this Apple's way of saying we should only connect them programmatically?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Correct. Set the delegate or other data in your `prepareForSegue:sender:` method. Here is an example:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Check the segue identifier
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"])
    {
        // Get a reference to your custom view controller
        CustomViewController *customViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        // Set your custom view controller's delegate
        customViewController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about setting the delegate for a UISplitViewController?  The sample code I'm looking at handles it by getting at the window's root view controller like this: `UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;`  While technically correct, and it works, it seems like a really dirty approach compared to the nice way delegates and view controllers were set before storyboards...

Answer (score 0):

If your storyboard segue destination View Controller is an UIViewController then @Marco answer is right. But if your destination View Controller is a UINavigationViewController then you have to get the UIViewController from UINavigationViewController :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Check the segue identifier
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"chooseCategoryType"])
    {
        // Get a reference of your custom view controller if your segue connection is an UIViewController
        // CustomViewController *customViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        // Get a reference of your custom view controller from navigation view controller if your segue connection is an UINavigationViewController
        CustomViewController *customViewController = [[[segue destinationViewController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

        // Set your custom view controller's delegate
        customViewController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```