# Storyboards and setting delegates

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

Now that Xcode 5 really encourages you work with storyboards, I'm making that my workflow. However having some trouble understanding initialization and setting delegates. (screen attached of my storyboard)

I have a Root View controller class that loads a navigation view controller into a container view. I want the root controller of the navigation controllers class to be the root controller of the storyboard. Without a storyboard, this would be incredibly simple.

In my root class I would simply write:

```
AlarmBarVC *aBar =  [[AlarmBarVC alloc]init];
UINavigationController *navcon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: aBar];

aBar.delegate = self;

self addChildViewController: navcon];
[self.container addSubview: navcon.view];
```

Any suggestion on how to implement this with Storyboards?

Thank you for your time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To set RootVC as the delegate to Alarm BarVC, select the Alarm BarVC in storyboard and navigate to the Connections inspector. Assuming you have created a property to hold the delegate in AlarmBarVC.h, you should see a delegate outlet that you can just drag to RootVC.

Comment: I see the delegate in the connections inspector, however I cannot drag it to anything outside of the AlarmBarVC ViewController in the storyboard

Comment: Hmm you're right. It seems that storyboards do not allow you to do set the delegate via outlets. You'll need to set the delegate in the prepareForSegue method. Here's a link to an identical question that was answered on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982128/storyboard-setting-delegates. Sorry for the wrong info in my first suggestion

Comment: Hi Mike, I appreciate your time, no need to apologize. I was looking at the segue methods but was hoping I didn't have to keep passing references through View Controllers that aren't going to use them. I'm probably going to go with a Singleton that manages the delegates/references.