# Is it possible to ctrl-drag in Storyboard to set a UINavigationControllerDelegate?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

In Xcode 5.0.2 I've created [an app for iPhone](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/MyAuth) with a navigation controller and 3 further view controllers (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSKUS.png)):

[image: xcode screenshot]

I'd like the [LoginViewController](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/MyAuth/MyAuth/LoginViewController.m) (with the "Login" title in the above screenshot) be the delegate for the navigation controller, so that its method

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
       didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated:(BOOL)animated
```

is called - so I have added the following code to its `viewDidLoad`:

```
UINavigationController *nc = self.navigationController;
[nc setDelegate:self];
```

This works, but I wonder if setting the delegate for the navigation controller is also possible in the Interface Builder?

I've tried ctrl-dragging from the yellow cube sign of the navigation controller to the LoginViewController scene and vice versa - but I'm only offered a popup to create a segue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: this answer might be outdated as of Dec 2015. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31221598/2128900) is probably more accurate for XCode 6 and newer.

Long long ago, before storyboards existed, setting delegates was possible using outlets (although I don't remember if it was possible for UINavigationController, I only remember that I did it with UITableView). You would just right-click on Navigation Controller and drag from the outlet to the target:

[image: outlets]

However, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9004561/2128900), it's not possible anymore. You can do it programatically in `viewDidLoad` as you did, or using `prepareForSegue:`.

Comment: I believe that this answer is not accurate. See my answer below.

Answer (score 11):

It is possible to do it in Interface Builder at least in Xcode 6.

1. Have a class that confirms to `UINavigationControllerDelegate`
2. In Interface Builder, from the Object library drag **Object** into your Navigation Controller (either into Document Outline or the toolbar above the Navigation Controller in Storyboard)
   [image]
3. Set Object's *Class* in Identity inspector to your `UINavigationControllerDelegate` class
   [image]
4. Ctrl-drag from the Navigation Controller object to your delegate object
   [image]
5. From the popup menu select "delegate"
   [image]

That's all. Now your object will be Navigation Controller's delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I am very new to Xcode, so this explanation may be completely wrong and not your question at all. If you are trying to link a view to a view controller, have you tried selecting the view and then setting a custom class to control it under the identity inspector?
Again, I don't quite understand your question, but I figured I'd try to help anyways.