# How can I set UINavigationController 's delegate in storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, xcode7

In `Home` View Controler I can do this to solve my problem

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  self.navigationController?.delegate = self
}
```

But I want to set the `UINavigationController`'s delegate in storyboard (don't want to write the code) and I'm unable to do that.
Anybody knows the trick or solution?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to ctrl-drag in Storyboard to set a UINavigationControllerDelegate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501286/is-it-possible-to-ctrl-drag-in-storyboard-to-set-a-uinavigationcontrollerdelegat)

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you take a UINavigationcontroller class and then set it in storyboard and set that delegate . So that you can override all the navigation controller delegate functions in one class only.